# Backshift operator in Dickey Fuller

Tags: augmented-dickey-fuller

[image]

Why does a backshift operator being equal to 1 mean that the data is non-stationary, shouldn't it be the coefficients or the phi 1 2 and 3 in this case?

[image]

Why does phi1 + phi2 + phi3 = 1 mean that there is a unit root?

Comment: Hi: I would skip the whole first part and just start with "So, having a unit root means:". I jave no idea why he's using an AR(3) and trying to somehow relate that to the ADF ?  Then, if you're still confused with the second part, I would read Hamilton's text. That should give a pretty good explanation of what's going on with Dickey Fuller and Augmented Dickey Fuller. Enders is less detailed but also decent.

Comment: @mlofton Hamilton's?

Comment: @sir.edwards:  I'm sorry. James Hamilton wrote a text that some regard as the bible of time series. It's title, IIRC,  is Time Series Analysis. There's another one by Enders ( maybe "applied economic time series" ) that is less heavy on the derivations but also should give the basic idea behind the unit root tests. Finally, you should search on this site. There are many old threads that discuss DF and ADF and I bet there are some good ones that explain it quite nicely.